# Picking up rows with conditional expression - Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In my dataframe, a column known as XC has the following values:

```html
XMORIG      YMORIG    ZMORIG      XC           YC           ZC    Index
14212.37 104364.2 1300 16774.83 107357.67 2852.5 534802
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17499.87 105601.7 2867.5 534803
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17474.87 105601.7 2867.5 521987
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17499.87 105626.7 2852.5 534878
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17499.87 105626.7 2867.5 534879
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17499.87 105676.7 2867.5 535033
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17524.87 105701.7 2867.5 548040
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17474.87 105601.7 2882.5 521988
14212.37 104364.2 1300 16774.83 105651.7 2882.5 534957
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17524.87 105701.7 2882.5 548041
14212.37 104364.2 1300 16762.74 107370.32 2882.5 547960
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17549.87 105726.7 2867.5 561192
14212.37 104364.2 1300 16762.54 105676.7 2897.5 547961
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17549.87 105701.7 2882.5 561111
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17549.87 105701.7 2897.5 561112
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17549.87 105676.7 2897.5 561031
14212.37 104364.2 1300 17474.87 105651.7 2867.5 522140
```

if `i = 16764.83`
i want to pick all those rows in which the value of `XC - i <= abs(12.5)`

i have tried `df.loc`, `df.query`,`pd.eval` but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure the values in column XC are `float` with

```
df['XC'].dtypes
```

After that you can simply use

```
df.loc[(df['XC'] - i) <= 12.5]
```

There is no need to use `abs()` since you're already declaring 12.5 as positive